# A complete exercise of Algebraic topology

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, covering-spaces

My teacher of Algebraic topology has shared exams from past years and this exercise appears on them:

> Consider the following sets on the Euclidean plane $\Bbb{R}^2$:
> $$X_1 = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2=1 \} \\
>   X_2 = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : 1 \leq x \leq 2 \, ; y=0 \} \\
>   X_3 = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : (x-3)^2 + y^2 \leq 1\} \\
>   X   = \bigcup_{k=1}^3 X_k$$
>
> 1. Compute, reasonably, the fundamental group of $X$.
> 2. For each $n\in \Bbb{Z}, n\geq 0$ compute a compact, path connected subspace $K_n \subseteq X$ whose fundamental group is the free group of degree $n$.
> 3. Describe a simply connected covering space $(\tilde{X}, p)$ of $X$ and describe clearly the $p$.
> 4. Let denote $Y=S^2 \vee \Bbb{R} \Bbb{P}^2$ and let $f: Y \rightarrow X$ a continuous map. Prove that $f$ is null-homotopic.
> 5. Let $k \in \Bbb{Z}, k \geq 1$. Construct a connected covering space $(\tilde{X_k}, p_k)$ of $X$ with exactly $k$ leafs. Let $x_0 \in X$ and for all $k \geq 1$ take $\tilde{x}_0^k \in p_k^{-1}(x_0)$. Determine the subgroup $H_k = {p_k}_\ast (\pi_1 (\tilde{X_k}, \tilde{x}_0^k) )$ of $\pi_ 1(X, x_0)$.

[image]

I am trying to solve it, so I want to know if my ideas are fine and what to do to complete it.

For 1., I think that, since the space $X$ is $\Bbb{S}^1$ $(X_1)$ connected by a segment $(X_2)$ with $\Bbb{D}^2$ $(X_3)$, it is clear that $\Bbb{S}^1$ is deformation retract of $X$, so $\pi_1 (X)= \pi_1 (\Bbb{S}^1) = \Bbb{Z}$.

For 2., I do not have clear what to do. It cames to me ideas like set $n-1$ circles indise of $X_3$ pairwise connected by a single point and one of them connected to $X_2$ on $(2,0)$, but I am not sure about this.

For 3., I am a little confused since my intuition says that, since $\Bbb{S}^1$ is deformation retract of $X$, it has to be some way to show that $\Bbb{R}$, who is the universal covering space of $\Bbb{S}^1$, it is the space looked for.

For 4., I have seen a theoretical result that every continuous map $f: X \rightarrow S^1$ is null-homotopic iff the induced homomorphism is trivial. Therefore, I think that it can be proved as well showing that the given map $f$ induces $f_\ast : \pi_1(Y) = \Bbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}$, but I do not know how to do this.

For 5., I am very stuck and do not know how to solve it, to be honest.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: $X$ is a deformation retract of $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{x_0,x_1\}$, where $x_0,x_1\in\mathbb{R}^2$ are two distinct points, so they have the same fundamental group namely the free group on $2$ elements. It also has the same homotopy type as the figure eight space and the theta space.

Comment: If you haven't seen the fundamental groups of those spaces, you should use the [Seifert-Van Kampen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93Van_Kampen_theorem#Equivalent_formulations) to prove that.

Comment: @VincentBatens Sorry but, that would not be if $X_3$ was be punctured? Since it is not, is not deformation retractable to $\Bbb{S}^1$

Comment: Ah I misread the question then. $X$ deformation retracts to $X_1$, so the fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}$, let me write an answer.

Comment: @VincentBatens nice, so it coincides with what I wrote. Btw, I already know SVK, but thanks :)

Comment: I'm stupid, didn't read.

Comment: Your question shouldn't consist of multiple questions

Comment: Wouldn’t just $n$ circles connected by edges inside $X_3$ work for (2)?

Comment: @Eric a point connected to $n$ circles works (homotopy equivalent to a wedge of circles),I don't know about your answer: do you mean that all circles are connected with each other? I don't think it works since lines will overlap and create extra holes

Comment: @Eric That is what I wrote, so is it fine?

Comment: @VincentBatens what do you mean? I do not see the relation of that with what Eric wrote

Comment: @VincentBatens What I mean with "pairwise connected by a single point" is this ∞

Comment: wait, what are your generators supposed to be?

Comment: @VincentBatens what do you mean by generators?

Comment: generators of your free group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150899/discussion-between-superdivinidad-and-vincent-batens).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For 1., I think that, since the space $X$ is $\Bbb{S}^1$ $(X_1)$ connected by a segment $(X_2)$ with $\Bbb{D}^2$ $(X_3)$, it is clear that $\Bbb{S}^1$ is deformation retract of $X$, so $\pi_1 (X)= \pi_1 (\Bbb{S}^1) = \Bbb{Z}$.

Looks correct.

> For 2., I do not have clear what to do. It cames to me ideas like set $n-1$ circles indise of $X_3$ pairwise connected by a single point and one of them connected to $X_2$ on $(2,0)$, but I am not sure about this.

Indeed. Except $n$ circles. The formula would be something like this:

$$C_i=\{(x,y)\ |\ (x+1/i)^2+y^2=(1/i)^2\}$$
$$K_n=\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$$

Then $K_n$ topologically is homeomorphic to $\bigvee_{i=1}^n S^1$ which is well known to have free fundamental group of rank $n$.

> For 3., I am a little confused since my intuition says that, since $\Bbb{S}^1$ is deformation retract of $X$, it has to be some way to show that $\Bbb{R}$, who is the universal covering space of $\Bbb{S}^1$, it is the space looked for.

No. Universal covering is uniquely determined up to homeomorphism, not homotopy equivalence. For example every contractible space is universal covering of itself, but clearly these don't have to be homeomorphic.

In this particular case $\Bbb{R}$ isn't even a covering of $X$, because every covering map is a local homeomorphism. Clearly the two-dimensional piece cannot be locally homeomorphic with $\Bbb{R}$.

Generally universal covering of wedge sum of two spaces is complicated. But it is quite straightforward if one of the pieces is simply connected. First take $\Bbb{R}$ (which is universal covering of $S^1$) and then glue to it a copy of $X_2\vee X_3$ at every integer $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. The resulting space is contractible and there's an obvious covering onto $X$, and thus it is the universal covering. The drawing:

[image]

> For 4., I have seen a theoretical result that every continuous map $f: X \rightarrow S^1$ is null-homotopic iff the induced homomorphism is trivial. Therefore, I think that it can be proved as well showing that the given map $f$ induces $f_\ast : \pi_1(Y) = \Bbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow \Bbb{Z}$, but I do not know how to do this.

You are almost there. You literally have to notice that there is no non-trivial group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}_2\to\mathbb{Z}$ because $\mathbb{Z}$ has no non-trivial finite subgroups.

> For 5., I am very stuck and do not know how to solve it, to be honest.

This is similar to the idea for the universal covering. First you take a covering $p_k:S^1\to S^1$ with $k$ leafs, i.e. $p_k(z)=z^k$ in terms of complex numbers. Then you attach copy of $X_2\vee X_3$ at every $k$-th root of unity in $S^1$. It is tempting to do the attaching in a smart way, i.e. by copying $X_2\vee X_3$ and rotating $k$ time. With such construction simple rotation becomes the covering map we are looking for. However the devil is in the details: for big enough $k$ copies of $X_2\vee X_3$ will intersect each other. And we don't want that. Therefore we need to do an abstract glueing at each $k$-th root of unity, and then consider a "projection" as the covering map. Here we project only copies of $X_2\vee X_3$ onto $X_2\vee X_3$, the base $S^1\to S^1$ stays as rotation $z\mapsto z^k$. The drawing for $k=4$:

[image]

As for the subgroup this requires some tedious calculations which follow from general properties of coverings. Both spaces have $\mathbb{Z}$ as the fundamental group and it can be shown that the induced morphism $(p_k)_*$ maps $[x]$ to $k[x]$. And so the subgroup we are looking for is $k\mathbb{Z}\subseteq\mathbb{Z}$. I'm not going to go into details on this one, feel free to ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answer!! It really helps

Comment: One question, in 3, why do we need to do it for every integer? Is it not enought to consider $\tilde{X}$ as $\Bbb{R} \vee X_2 \vee X_3$ following your idea?

Comment: @Superdivinidad it doesn't have to be an integer. Its just that typically the universal covering $p:\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ is defined as $p(t)=exp(2\pi i t)$ and then $p^{-1}(1)=\mathbb{Z}$. And complex $1=(1,0)$ is the point of glueing $X_2\vee X_3$ with $X_1$. And therefore back in the universal covering this piece has to correspond (locally) to integers, i.e. we need to glue a (local) copy of $X_2\vee X_3$ at every integer.

Comment: Remember that each fiber of a covering has the same cardinality. And the universal covering $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ has each fiber infinite countable. This gives us a hint that perhaps the universal covering of $S^1\vee X_2\vee X_3$ will also have each fiber infinite. Assuming it is somehow related to the universal covering of $S^1$. And this leads to another conclusion, that maybe we need to glue infinitely many copies of $X_2\vee X_3$ to $\Bbb{R}$ to obtain this covering. It turns out that this idea works. That was my reasoning here.

Comment: And all of that generalizes as follows: if $p:X\to Y$ is a covering, $Z$ is any space, then $X'=X\vee \bigvee_{p^{-1}(y_0)} Z$ is a covering of $Y\vee Z$ ($Y$ glued to $Z$ at $y_0$). Here in $X'$ we glue a copy of $Z$ at every point in $p^{-1}(y_o)$. Additionally if $X$ is universal and $Z$ simply connected, then $X'$ is also universal.

Comment: I see, that is pretty well thought out. So, in this case if I am not wrong, can we take for example $ \tilde{X} = \cup_{k \in \Bbb{Z}} \{ x \leq 2, y = 2k \} \vee \overline{B}_1 (3, 2k)$ ?

Comment: @Superdivinidad no, you take single vertical line $\{0\}\times\Bbb{R}$ and then you glue a copy of $X_2\vee X_3$ at every $(0,k)$. Also be careful about real geometric constructions: you need to make sure balls don't intersect each other. I assume that's why you are doing $2k$, which is nice observation. Me, on the other hand, I prefer to talk about glueing, i.e. [wedge sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedge_sum). Which is not the same thing, wedge sum is safer, components are isolated by construction.

Comment: I've added drawings to the answer.